# Can the Whitaker Nusselt number correlation be used for a hot sphere in convection with cool air?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, chemical-engineering, convection

The Whitaker Nusselt number correlation ([equation 4 here if you don't know it](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4648403/)) seems to not be applicable for when the viscosity of the fluid gets higher away from the surface, but it seems to get used in problems where we have a hot sphere in convection with air, which would always violate this boundary as the viscosity term would be below 1. Does this mean it is not applicable? Or can it be adapted for gas use as opposed to liquid use?